# Textmate Bundles - How to find the right ones, and is it possible to use more than one at the same time?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

I've just decided to try switching over to TextMate from Komodo and I'm wondering how to determine what the best bundles are to use. I primarily code in HTML, CSS, JS, & PHP.

I'm wondering if there are places where bundles are reviewed. For example, when looking for a CSS bundle in the GetBundles window, I get maybe 30-40 options. How do I know which one to use? Seems like just trying out random ones could get a bit time consuming...

I'm also curious to know whether it's possible to use multiple bundles at the same time. For example, I code a lot in jQuery, so I have the jQuery bundle by kswedberg. But perhaps there is a better general JS bundle for non-jQuery JS. In that case, is it possible to use both at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official place to discuss this subject that I know of. You'll need to install each of them and study their features in the "Edit Bundles" window.

The default ("pristine") bundles all work very well. If I remember correctly, most of the alternative bundles are essentially framework/library specific. Or they are variants of the default ones customized by other users. If you find something missing there is nothing stopping you from adding it yourself. That's possibly TextMate's greatest strength.

If you are into code editing you should take a little more risk, don't you think? Why not install all of the JQuery bundles and see how it goes? You'd have your answer a lot faster than asking here.

Anyway, yes, you can use overlapping bundles together without problems: hitting a shortcut registered by two or more bundles is just going to display a nice little contextual menu with all the available actions for you to choose. Same for snippets.

There is [another JS bundle](https://github.com/subtleGradient/javascript.tmbundle) worth installing, it has a lot of useful snippets and minification/syntax checking.